# Why is mod_usertrack not setting cookie?

Tags: httpd, httpd.conf

I am running httpd:2.4.57 in docker. I have not figured out how to set or see the cookie set by mod_usertrack. I checked both browsers to be sure cookies were allowed.

I verified the mod_usertrack.so file exists in the container and is referred to correctly.

```
$ ls -al | grep usertrack
-rwxr-xr-x 1 httpd httpd   43976 Oct 11 20:23 mod_usertrack.so
```

These are the directives within httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so

CookieTracking on
CookieName session_id
CookieHTTPOnly on
CookieSecure off
CookieStyle RFC2965
CookieSameSite Strict

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%{session_id}n %r %t" common    
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
</IfModule>
```

And here is an example of what is output to my log:

`- GET /api/pictures HTTP/1.1 [23/Oct/2023:19:27:29 +0000]`

Based on what I read at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_usertrack.html, a cookie by the name of session_id should be set.  I cannot see the cookie either in the logs or in my webdev tools in Chrome or Firefox.

As requested by  @vidarlo, here is the output of `curl -I ...` where I had to add `--insecure` to ignore my self-signed certificate:

```
$ curl -I --insecure  https://localhost:8443 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2023 19:50:58 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie2: session_id=87aa60b1.608678a7cc2f9; path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure; HttpOnly
Last-Modified: Fri, 20 Oct 2023 14:46:20 GMT
ETag: "1e7f-60826ef88e48a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 7807
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: What does `curl -I http://url` show?

Comment: Updated my question to answer you, @vidarlo

Comment: Interestingly and unexpectedly, the value of session_id changes with each request.

Comment: Interestingly, I see it sets the `Set-Cookie2` header instead of just `Set-Cookie`.  That would explain why it is not showing up in my webdev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Interestingly and unexpectedly, the value of session_id changes with each request.

That's not unexpected. It's generated *unless* a previous value is present in the request.

> Interestingly, I see it sets the Set-Cookie2 header instead of just Set-Cookie. That would explain why it is not showing up in my webdev tools.

Try adding

```
CookieStyle Cookie
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_usertrack.html#cookiestyle

Comment: I appreciate you suggesting I use `CookieStyle Cookie`.  That got my browser to recognize it and set it and it doesn't change with each request.  I feel like the documentation could have been more clear.  `Set-Cookie2` is deprecated, is it not?

Comment: I believe it is, Apache claims it isn't. I'm not an expert in HTTP headers...